# Gedmo Timestampable always updating reference when deserializing with JMS Serializer

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I have a one-to-one relationship in my Symfony2 Project where a `Question` has a reference to a `Video` - both have a *created* and *updated* *Gedmo\Timestampable* behaviour which is basically working as expected. But a little bit too much:

When deserializing the `Question` with the attached `Video` (as ID only to avoid other changes in the *Video metadata*) the `Video` document **always** gets an update both on the `created` **and** the `updated` field. This doesn't seem right. I may understand why the updated field gets a new date - even if actually nothing has changed on the object itself, but why *created* ?

This is my code (simplyfied):

Class Question:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Question
 *
 * @Serializer\AccessorOrder("alphabetical")
 * @MongoDB\Document(
 *   collection="Quiz",
 *   repositoryClass="MyNamespace\Bundle\QuizBundle\Repository\QuestionRepository",
 * )
 * @package MyNamespace\Bundle\QuizBundle\Document
 */
class Question
{
    /**
     * @var \MongoId
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
     * @Serializer\Type("string")
     * @Serializer\Groups({
     *   "quiz_admin_list",
     *   "quiz_admin_detail"
     * })
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Assert\Date(
     *   message = "quiz:constraints.model.question.created.invalid"
     * )
     * @Serializer\Type("DateTime<'U'>")
     * @Serializer\Accessor(getter="getCreated", setter="setCreatedEmpty")
     * @Serializer\Groups({
     *   "quiz_admin_list",
     *   "quiz_admin_detail"
     * })
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @MongoDB\Date
     */
    protected $created;


    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Assert\Date(
     *   message = "quiz:constraints.model.question.updated.invalid"
     * )
     * @Serializer\Type("DateTime<'U'>")
     * @Serializer\Accessor(getter="getUpdated", setter="setUpdatedEmpty")
     * @Serializer\Groups({
     *   "quiz_admin_list",
     *   "quiz_admin_detail"
     * })
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @MongoDB\Date
     */
    protected $updated;

    /**
     * @var Video
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("MyNamespace\Bundle\CoreMediaAdminBundle\Document\Video")
     * @Serializer\Groups({
     *   "quiz_admin_list",
     *   "quiz_admin_detail"
     * })
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(
     *   targetDocument="MyNamespace\Bundle\CoreMediaAdminBundle\Document\Video",
     *   cascade={"all"}
     * )
     */
    protected $answerVideo;

}
```

Class Video:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Video
 * @Serializer\AccessorOrder("alphabetical")
 * @MongoDB\Document(
 *   collection="CoreMediaAdminVideo",
 *   repositoryClass="MyNamespace\Bundle\CoreMediaAdminBundle\Repository\VideoRepository",
 * )
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 * @package MyNamespace\Bundle\CoreMediaAdminBundle\Document
 */
class Video 
{

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
     * @Serializer\Type("string")
     * @Serializer\Groups({
     *   "core_media_list",
     *   "core_media_search",
     *   "core_media_video_list",
     *   "core_media_video_detail"
     * })
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(
     *   mapping = "core_media_admin_video",
     *   fileNameProperty = "fileName"
     * )
     * @Serializer\Exclude
     * @var File $file
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     * @Serializer\Type("string")
     * @Serializer\Groups({
     *   "core_media_list",
     *   "core_media_search",
     *   "core_media_video_list",
     *   "core_media_video_detail"
     * })
     */
    protected $mimeType;

    /**
     * @var String
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *   message = "core.media.admin:constraints.model.base.title.not_blank"
     * )
     * @Serializer\Type("string")
     * @Serializer\Groups({
     *   "core_media_list",
     *   "core_media_search",
     *   "core_media_video_list",
     *   "core_media_video_detail"
     * })
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Assert\Date(
     *   message = "core.media.admin:constraints.model.base.date.invalid"
     * )
     * @Serializer\Type("DateTime<'U'>")
     * @Serializer\Accessor(getter="getCreated", setter="setCreatedEmpty")
     * @Serializer\Groups({
     *   "core_media_list",
     *   "core_media_search",
     *   "core_media_video_list",
     *   "core_media_video_detail"
     * })
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @MongoDB\Date
     */
    protected $created;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Assert\Date(
     *   message = "core.media.admin:constraints.model.base.date.invalid"
     * )
     * @Serializer\Type("DateTime<'U'>")
     * _Serializer\Accessor(getter="getUpdated", setter="setUpdatedEmpty")
     * @Serializer\Groups({
     *   "core_media_list",
     *   "core_media_search",
     *   "core_media_video_list",
     *   "core_media_video_detail"
     * })
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @MongoDB\Date
     */
    protected $updated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Assert\Date(
     *   message = "core.media.admin:constraints.model.base.date.invalid"
     * )
     * @Serializer\Type("DateTime<'U'>")
     * @Serializer\Groups({
     *   "core_media_list",
     *   "core_media_search",
     *   "core_media_video_list",
     *   "core_media_video_detail"
     * })
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update", field={"title", "tags", "comment", "dataOrigin", "description", "videoMetaData", "mimeType", "fileName", "file" })
     * @MongoDB\Date
     */
    protected $updatedContent;

}
```

The interesting thing is, no changes are made on `Video` objects during deserialization - there is **only** the update Query to set the `created` and `updated` fields of the Video.. I also tested the *field* parameter for Timestampable to force an update only when one of those fields get an update but this seems to be ignored completely.

Here is also the JSON which is deserialized and the corresponding MongoDB queries:

```
{
  "id": "547f31e650e56f2c26000063",
  "question_id": 12,
  "question_text": "Wer einen Gemüsegarten hat, sollte wissen, dass Schnecken…?",
  "answer_text": "test",
  "answer_video": {
    "id": "547f31d850e56f2c26000031"
  },
  "tags": [
    "Schnecken",
    "Basilikum",
    "Thymian",
    "Garten"
  ]
}
```

Queries:

```
db.QuizQuestion.find({
  "_id": ObjectId("547f31e650e56f2c26000063")
}).limit(1).limit();

db.CoreMediaAdminVideo.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("547f31d850e56f2c26000031")
},
{
  "$set": {
    "created": newISODate("2014-12-03T21:30:02+01:00"),
    "updated": newISODate("2014-12-03T21:30:02+01:00"),
    "updatedContent": newISODate("2014-12-03T21:30:02+01:00")
  }
});

db.ARDBuffetQuizQuestion.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("547f31e650e56f2c26000063")
},
{
  "$set": {
    "created": newISODate("2014-12-03T21:30:02+01:00"),
    "updated": newISODate("2014-12-03T21:30:02+01:00"),
    "questionText": "Wer einen Gemüsegarten hat, sollte wissen, dass Schnecken…?",
    "answerText": "test",
    "answerVideo": {
      "$ref": "CoreMediaAdminVideo",
      "$id": ObjectId("547f31d850e56f2c26000031"),
      "$db": "my-database"
    }
  }
});

db.ARDBuffetQuizQuestion.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("547f31e650e56f2c26000063")
},
{
  "$set": {
    "tags": [
      {
        "value": "Schnecken",
        "normalized": "schnecken"
      },
      {
        "value": "Basilikum",
        "normalized": "basilikum"
      },
      {
        "value": "Thymian",
        "normalized": "thymian"
      },
      {
        "value": "Garten",
        "normalized": "garten"
      }
    ]
  }
});

db.ARDBuffetQuizQuestion.find({
  "_id": ObjectId("547f31e650e56f2c26000063")
}).limit(1).limit();

db.CoreMediaAdminVideo.find({
  "_id": ObjectId("547f31d850e56f2c26000031")
}).limit(1).limit();
```

Comment: you do $set createdAt and updatedAt manually in your query, or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gedmo\Timestampable will set (new) values for `$created` and `$updated` because that data isn't present when flushing the ObjectManager.

Although the annotations in class `Video` define that `$created` and `$updated` should be included when serializing such an object, the JSON you show doesn't contain those keys/properties.

Here's what happens:

- The JSON doesn't contain the keys/properties `created` and `updated`.
- When deserializing, the resulting object will have `null` values for `$created` and `$updated`.
- When `merge()`-ing the object into the ObjectManager, nothing happens with it. The object simply becomes "managed", which means that during a flush, the ObjectManager will calculate the change-set for it and update it if necessary.
- When flushing the ObjectManager, Gedmo\Timestampable will kick in (due to a `PreUpdate` event listener). It will see that `$created` and `$updated` contain `null` values, so it will assign new values.
- Then the ObjectManager will retrieve the "current" data from the database, because it needs it to calculate the change-set. Normally, when `find()`-ing an object, it won't do this because the data is already retrieved during that `find()`.
- Because the values of `$created` and `$updated` are now different from those retrieved from the database, it will update them.

So you'll have 2 options:

1. `find()` the object first, then change it according to the JSON.
2. Make sure the JSON contains *all* properties that are mapped (including `created` and `updated`).

Also, I noticed `setter="setCreatedEmpty"` and `setter="setUpdatedEmpty"`. I'm not sure what those methods do (because you don't show us), but the method-names indicate something other that simply assigning values.

#### Answer to your comments

When `merge()`-ing an object into the ObjectManager, it is marked as "dirty", which will trigger the calculation of a change-set. And because the reference of the DateTime objects has changed (the instances that Doctrine got from the db are always different from the instances that were created by deserializing JSON), the object will be updated. Then Gedmo\Timestampable will kick in and change the `$updated` property accordingly.

If you don't want this to happen, you'll need to `find()` the current object, and *only* change value objects when the value they represent actually changed. Scalar values are no problem: you can set the same value and Doctrine won't see it as a change. But with value objects (like DateTime) objects, Doctrine will see a change when there reference changes (when a different instance is set).

Comment: tl;dr: You are right. It worked. :)

I was using `setter="setCreatedEmpty"` because in a past project (about 14 months ago) I had a similar issue with doctrine mongodb & jms serializer and for some reason, *not* setting the created/updated values again on deserilization solved the problem. So was simply re-using this workaround. Now, when all data is included Doctrine _still_ does an update query on referenced videos _but_ is keeping the original `created` timestamp as you proposed. I was hoping to avoid additional queries. Anyways, it works and no more confusing 'created' timestamps. Thanks.

Comment: Still one question left: when somebody else would update a Video and give it proper new updated timestamp, doing it this way would overwrite the updated timestamp again - so to be 100% sure, i should fetch the referenced object from the database and compare values right? - Or _if_ there is a way to avoid the additional query, it wouldn't happen at al..